# discord.js can not read property'id' of undefined when bulk delete messages

Tags: discord.js

I have been working on a bulk delete message logs, but for whatever reason it can not get the ID of the channel from the guild in a seperate file. so it returns that ID is undefined.

**THE CODE**

```js
module.exports = async (bot, messages) => {
  const length = messages.array().length
  let channels = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('././database/messageChannel.json', 'utf8')
  );
  let channelId = channels[messages.guild.id].channel;
  let msgChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId);

  if (!msgChannel) {
    return console.log(`No message channel found with ID ${channelId}`);
  }
  let mEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(messages.guild.name, messages.guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
  .setColor(red_light)
  .setDescription(`**Bulk Delete in <#${messages.channel.id}>, ${length} messages deleted.**`)
  .setTimestamp()
  msgChannel.send(mEmbed)
}
```

In the index file I specified the

```js
messageDeleteBulk
```

When trying to send the message to the messageChannel it does not send because 'id' is undefined. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the command works fine all I forgot was that earlier when I defined length I used
`messages.first()`so where I just put `messages` I have to add `.first()`

**THE NEW CODE**

```js
module.exports = async (bot, messages) => {
  let channels = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('././database/messageChannel.json', 'utf8')
  );
  let channelId = channels[messages.first().guild.id].channel;
  let msgChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId);

  if (!msgChannel) {
    return console.log(`No message channel found with ID ${channelId}`);
  }
    const length = messages.array().length;
  let mEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(messages.first().guild.name, messages.first().guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
  .setColor(red_light)
  .setDescription(`**Bulk Delete in <#${messages.first().channel.id}>, ${length} messages deleted.**`)
  .setTimestamp()
  msgChannel.send(mEmbed)
}
```

Now it logs the bulk deleted messages and does not return any errors.